# After adding item redirect to the listview page

Tags: web-part, list-view, custom-list, item-added

I have created a page in **SharePoint 2013**. This has a **web-part** which shows a list view of a **custom-list**. From this page when I add an item it redirects to the default **list-view** page. I want it to redirect after adding item to my created page.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

At your Custom page that have a list view of a custom-list. add script editor and then add this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").removeAttribute("onclick");


document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href="http://epm/workflow/Lists/Shoe%20Models/NewForm.aspx?Source=add your custom page url";

});
```

At `document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href=` put your link to NewForm before `Source Query String` and after it add your Custom Page URL that you want to go back.